# What Internet Voice Services Can Asterisk be Connected To

Tags: asterisk, skype, pbx

Does anyone know of any internet voice services, apart from GoogleTalk, Google Voice and Skype that Asterisk can be connected to for free?
Also, does anyone know how to connect Asterisk to Skype for free?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk can be connect to Gtalk via chan_motif

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google

Asterisk can be connected to skype using skype connect(payed montly). All other connections to skype from asterisk are illegal so can't be discussed here.